# build this layout in xml?

Tags: android, listactivity

I have a listActivity and wanted to create a list with the second layout (attached). What has any idea how to build this layout in xml?!

[show imageAttached](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1b4470d49f.png)

Answer (score 2):

I propose `RelativeLayout`

One picture will has `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Another picture has `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Text (and something else in the middle part) will be located in another layout (e.g `LinearLayout`) but with attribute, smth like following:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgLeft"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgRight"
```

Answer (score 0):

A horizontal LinearLayout with some gravity, and some [styled text](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/text/Html.html) or from Html will do the middle step.

Comment: Hi, Pentium10...

I'm not worried about the styles and links, do not want it.
What I want is a list where each line has two sentences (one below the other) and a final image. Similar to the application of twitter.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to use `holder.imageView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myStringWithHtmlInIt));` where you can put in standard `<br />`, `<b>` & `<font>` and other html formatting tags to do this type of thing...